# Store Character and Numerical Value inside a fortran variable

Tags: fortran, character

I have a population of N people. Then randomly I shall have to assign their sex male or female. Also they need to be randomly assigned some wealth.

Then the further arithmetical operation will be different for males and females, i.e, the if the person is male his wealth in next step shall be 1.2 times and if female, say will be 1.5 times, the scheme is something like that.

How can I implement this in fortran? For this I shall have to store the wealth and gender of people inside an array. Is there any way of storing a character like 'Male' and also some numerical value for wealth both inside a fortran variable?

Like, If a(100) is male, then the wealth of a(100)=a(100)*1.2 in next step.

How to implement this by storing both character and numerical value  inside an array in fortran?

Comment: A _derived type_ may well be suitable for this.  However, explaining how to use such things is the purpose of a tutorial and is too broad to be a useful answer here.  If you can focus your question with what you know about derived types then we can provide specific help.

Comment: I second @francescalus's comment.  OP might care to look around this site for Qs and As on the topic of Fortran's derived types, OP might learn much.